# Dynamically set attribute for child directive in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want dynamically set attributes for child directive.
But I can not do it.

> In the example I want to set attribute `name` with value `John`.

UPD:  In this case, I can not determine the exact set of attributes. And I need to define them dynamically. For example, this is part of a third-party library.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
  .directive('wrapper', wrapper);

angular.module('app')
  .directive('inWrapper', inWrapper);

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'), ['app']
);

function wrapper() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, ctrl,  transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(
        scope,
        function(clone) {
          clone.find('in-wrapper').attr('name', 'John');
        }
      );
    }
  }
}

function inWrapper() {
  return {
    scope: {
      name: '@'
    },
    template: 'Hello, {{name}}',
    link: function linkFunc(scope) {
      if (!scope.name) {
        scope.name = 'Empty';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <wrapper>
    <in-wrapper></in-wrapper>
  </wrapper>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to link the attribute to a scope variable.  If you are talking about designing the directive yourself, you can define the controller's scope variables as "=" and they will link bidirectionally to the value passed to the attribute.   Check the [AngularJS: Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more info.

You might also be able to assign the value of the attribute using {{...}} annotation to inject a scope variable directly into the markup.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I do not need to provide data to child directive. In this case, I can not determine the exact set of attributes. And I need to define them dynamically.

Comment: Ah okay.  I misunderstood the original question then.  Not sure how you would accomplish that.  But perhaps a workaround would be to have a single generic attribute that can accept a JSON object and have the directive inspect the properties of the object to determine functionality based on property names?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to set attributes dynamically but failed.
I suggest instead providing data for attributes in the item area directly.
In the code examples, I modified elements inside the transclude function. And provided data for attribute elements in the controller. Code not ideal. Only for demonstration idea.

P.S. Thanks @CodeMonkey for criticizing the original idea

```js
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app").directive("wrapper", wrapper);

angular.module("app").directive("inWrapper", inWrapper);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("root"), ["app"]);

function wrapper() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    controller: function linkFn($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
      var transcludedContent, transclusionScope,
        statuses = [
          'danger',
          'success',
          'info'
        ];
      status = 0;
      $transclude(function(clone, scope) {
        $element.append(clone);
        transcludedContent = clone;
        transclusionScope = scope;
        for (var i = 0, ii = clone.length; i < ii; i++) {
          var node = clone[i];
          if (node.nodeType !== 3 ||
            node.nodeValue.trim()) {
            node.classList.add(statuses[status]);
            status++;
          }
        }
      });
      // find scope for angulars element and provide data
      var elements = $element.find("in-wrapper");
      for (var i = 0, ii = elements.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var isolateScope = angular.element(elements[i]).isolateScope();
        isolateScope.name = 'World' + isolateScope.$id;

      }

    }
  };
}

function inWrapper() {
  return {
    scope: {
      name: "@"
    },
    template: '<div>Hello, <span ng-bind="name"></span></div>'
  };
}
```

```css
.danger {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.success {
  color: #00ff00;
}

.info {
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <wrapper>
    <in-wrapper></in-wrapper>
    <in-wrapper></in-wrapper>
    <in-wrapper></in-wrapper>
  </wrapper>
</div>
```